# Assign AWK result to variable

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, scripting, awk

This should be pretty straightfoward and I don't know why I am struggling with it.

I am running the following psql command from within a shell script in order to find out whether all indexes have been dropped before inserting data.

```
INDEXCOUNT=$(psql -p $dbPort -U enterprisedb -d main_db -c "select Count(*) from all_indexes where index_schema = 'enterprisedb';")
```

At this point, INDEXCOUNT is equal to “COUNT ------- 0”

Now if I echo the following line I get the result I want -

```
echo $INDEXCOUNT | awk '{print $3}'
```

How do I assign the value of `$INDEXCOUNT | awk ‘{print $3}’` to a variable to check it in an “IF” statement?

For example:

```
RETURNCOUNT=$INDEXCOUNT | awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The following works correctly on bash:

```
 a=$(echo '111 222 33' | awk '{print $3;}' )
 echo $a # result is "33"
```

Another option would be to convert the string to an array:

```
 a="111 222 333"
 b=($a)

 echo ${b[2]}  # returns 333
```

Comment: RETURNCOUNT=$(echo $INDEXCOUNT | awk '{print $3}')

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RETURNCOUNT=`echo $INDEXCOUNT | awk '{print $3}'`
```

The idea is to include any shell command between backticks to get the result into a variable.

Comment: `"$INDEXCOUNT"` is unlikely to be a command.

Comment: @glenn: In that case do echo can be used... The idea is to include any shell command between backticks to get the result into a variable

Comment: `$()` is preferred over `backticks` as it makes nesting commands easier

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can directly use:

```
${INDEXCOUNT##* }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to use for testing with if statement/

```
INDEXCOUNT="111 222 333"
echo $INDEXCOUNT | awk '{if ($3 == 333) print $3}';
```