# Bash: remove an array element which contains a value in another array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to remove the elements of an array which contains the elements of an other array.

EG

> **array1 = (aaaa bbbb abcd)**
>
> **array2 = (b c)**
>
> **result = (aaaa)**

I've wrote this piece of code but it doesn't work

```
for element in "${array2[@]}"
    do
        result=(${array1[@]/.*$element.*})
    done
```

could you tell me why and what should I do instead?

Comment: Please include the expected and actual result in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken that you need comma as a separator between the elements of the array. But the comma actually becomes a part of an element.
Other than that, the `result` won't wok either as you need to aggregate the removed elements. But `result` is assigned from `array1`. So the *element* removed 
from the previous iteration will again be a part of `resut`.

```
array1=(aaaa bbbb abcd)
array2=(b c)   
result=("${array1[@]}")

for element in "${array2[@]}"
do
     result=(${result[@]/*${element}*/})
done

echo "${result[@]}"
```

This copies the array into `result` array and removes elements from it using `array2`.

Comment: I'm sorry, the comma is only a mistake in reporting.
There are no commas in the code in which I have the problem.
By the way thanks for the tip...I didn't notice it!
I'm going to edit and correct my post.

Comment: I figured that. The issue was also with your substitution. You  can see the difference in the answer. You can also work with `array1` itself if you are OK to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stab at it.
I'm pretty sure this could be done completely with `awk` but I havn't found out how yet:

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=(aaaa bbbb abcd)
array2=(b c)   
result=()
for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
   sumIndexOf=0
   for j in "${array2[@]}"
   do
        sumIndexOf=$((sumIndexOf + $(echo $i $j | awk '{print index($1,$2)}')))     
   done
   if [ "$sumIndexOf" = "0" ]; then
        result+=($i)
   fi   
done
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}"
```

References/Used:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17695693/1688441
- [Bash: add value to array without specifying a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/bash-add-value-to-array-without-specifying-a-key)
- [Assign AWK result to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031612/assign-awk-result-to-variable)